# Best way to send image using socket

Tags: java, sockets

What is the best way to send image using socket in java ?
Or it's just a one way to converted to string of base 64?

Comment: I would save the image as bytes in the format or your choice e.g. png, and set it unencoded otherwise it will use more bytes to send the same data. e.g. base64 uses an extra 1/3rd more bytes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's clear that base64 isn't the ideal solution , but when using socket , there is any other way to send the image ?

Comment: @ArolaAb: Yes, by writing a program using the sockets API, which we won't do for you.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I already did it , I am just asking if there a better solution using sockets

Comment: You can either send the image as bytes and close the stream, or if you want to keep the stream, send the length e.g. a 4 byte integer followed by the image.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to send image using socket in Java?

Same way you send anything else. Just send the bytes.